# Ajax django POST requests ends prematuraly

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have data that is being submitted from a webpage. I try to re-validate the data on the server side before inserting to DB. For some reason the POST code isn't entirely executed. It reaches the validation with datetime.date() and returns. I am not getting any error or anything.

**Screen prints:**

> New assignment added

**Expected screen prints:**

> New assignment added
>
> Test2
>
> Submit here

The code below is for the view.py:

```
def addStudent(request, assignment, studentID= -1):
         #Check if POST
         if request.method == 'POST':
                 errors = []
                 print "New assignment added"
                 #Verify exam date is future and end date is after start
                 if request.POST['startD'] <= datetime.date():
                         print "Error"
                         errors.append("Please verify date is in the future")
                 print "Test2"
                 if request.POST['endD'] < request.POST['startD']:
                         errors.append("Please verify end date>start date.")
                 print "Submit here"
                 return
     return render(request,.....)
```

The following is the code that calls it:

```
    $.ajax({type: 'POST',
                  url:'/assignment/newassignment/{{university}}/',
                  data:{
                       csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',
                       studentName:$("#studentName").val(),
                       startD:$("#startDate").val(),
                       endD:$("#endDate").val()},
                  async:true});
```

**Disclaimer:** The code cannot be a form since visual manipulation is done by the user on the page. Several calls with the ajax are done for each student.

**Update**:
Tried the following debugging:

```
if request.POST['startD']:
                        print "date.today():"+str(date.today())
                        print "request:"+str(request.POST['startD'])
                        print "myDate:"+str(datetime.strptime(request.POST['startD'], "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

The first 2 statements are printed and the third isn't

**Screen prints:**

> date.today():2016-03-24
>
> request:2016-03-30

**IMPORTANT**:
from datetime import datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd imagine you're getting a server error since you're trying to compare values passed across as strings (`startD`/`endD`) to dates. You need to convert them to dates before the comparisons

```
start = request.POST.get('startD')
if start:
    start_date = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('startD'), "%Y-%m-%d")
    if start_date <= datetime.date():
```